# My CentOS 7 machine suddenly only boots into emergency mode

Tags: linux, boot, centos, computer-science

Last night I was working on my computer and it froze. I think it's graphic card related, I do have an Nvidia card.  So I rebooted the computer as I had no other option, but now it boots to emergency mode.

In `journalctl -xb` there are some errors. Other then this I am out of my league here guys. Should all these errors be fixed?

```
Systemd[1]: failed to apply kernel variables  
Sudo[17755] pam_systemd(sudo:session): failed to connect to system bus: no such file or directory found.
kernel: EXT4-fs (md0): can’t find ext file system.
Failed to mount /data01
Edac abridge: cpu srcid #0, ha #0 has dimms, but ecc is disabled.
Edac: couldn’t find mci handler
Edac: failed to register device with error -19
Systemd-udevd[1422]: failed to execute ‘/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper’ ‘/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper add snap_pulseaudio_pulseaudio /devices/pci0000:00
KVM disabled by bio
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue! I had to create the RAID volume. First create the RAID:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mkdir /data01
```

Mount the file system

```
mount /dev/md0 /data01
```

Now inspect your `/etc/fstab`, make sure things make sense in there.

```
vi /etc/fstab /dev/md0 /mnt/raid5 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

In my file I had to change the second column from `x` to `/mnt/raid5`.

Then I rebooted and it worked.